# How do I deploy an Express server to GitHub Pages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, github, github-pages

I was told that it is possible to deploy Express server to GitHub Pages but didn't really understand how. Do you just deploy it like you deploy a regular Pages repo?

Comment: Where were you told that?  I've never heard of that.  There is a content engine you can plug into if your pages use a template system, but that's not your own Express server.

Answer (score 7):

GitHub pages host only static HTML pages. No server-side technology is supported, so Express applications won't run on GitHub pages.

Instead, you can look into using other affordable providers like [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), or [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/).