# Socket.io deploy to gh-pages

Tags: javascript, express, sockets, github-pages

So I am doing a little study on socket.io and I wanted to deploy to my gh-pages.

I am able to deploy it, but as I was doing it standalone on localhost.

But I can't seem to figure out what port to use for gh-pages and I keep getting 404 error on socket.io

```
//Client Side  
var socket = io('https://chokitu.github.io/chatsecreto/'); // I am assuming I should have a port here.
```

```
//Server Side
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "https://chokitu.github.io",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
server.listen(port);
```

I think those are the lines that would be useful.

I am kind of new to express and socket so...

And that's the error I am getting:
`polling-xhr.js:157 GET https://chokitu.github.io/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NtV5xap 404`

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/67575139/8887313

GitHub pages will host your client side files and run some static site generators (Jekyll, etc.) but will not host a server for you. There are various platforms that you can deploy your server side code, for example on AWS/Azure/GCP or Heroku.

Comment: LOL, I Literally looked all over the place and didn't find the duplicate, thanks tho!!